# Excel - Adding time due to specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help creating a formula in Excel. I want the formula to look at the value in a cell. If the value is "telephone", I want it to add 5 minutes to my elapsed time. If the value is "email/Fax", I want it to add 2-1/2 minutes. Please help?

Comment: sounds like you need an `IF` statement (https://support.office.com/en-in/article/IF-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb)

Comment: Thank you, Roberto. I tried searching the support articles you posted but still didn't quite understand who to write the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Say the elapsed time is in **A1** and the text is in cell **B1**
In cell **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="telephone",A1+TIME(0,5,0),IF(B1="email/Fax",A1+TIME(0,2,30),A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Gary's Student - Thank you so much! That worked beautifully! I sincerely appreciate you!